# Getting dynamically form inputs and parse them to FromModel's list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a lecture and this lecture can have an unknown number of descriptions. I want to add them to a list so I can save the lecture with the given description.

This is the form model:
[Add Lecture From Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWXmy.png)

```
 public class AddLectureFormModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(MaxNameLength,
            ErrorMessage = "{0} should be between {2} and {1} letters",
            MinimumLength = MinNameLength)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public string CourseId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<AddDescriptionFormModel> Descriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is Form Model for the descriptions:
[Add Description Form Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfrjS.png) as

```
public class AddDescriptionFormModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(
            MaxNameLength,
            ErrorMessage = "{0} should be between {2} and {1} letters",
            MinimumLength = MinNameLength)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is how I'm trying to add them
[Fields adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgXRK.png)

```
let index = 0;
        document.getElementById('add-description').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let parentDiv = e.currentTarget.parentNode;

            let html = `<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="text-light" asp-for="Descriptions[${index}].Name"></label>
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Descriptions[${index}].Name" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Descriptions[${index}].Name" class="small text-danger"></span>
                </div>`;

            $(html).insertBefore(parentDiv);
        })
```

And this is how I wait for the result in my Lecture Controller

```
public IActionResult Add(string courseId)
        {
            if (guard.AgainstNull(courseId, nameof(courseId))) return BadRequest();

            if (!courseService.GetCourseById(courseId)) return NotFound();

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(string courseId, AddLectureFormModel lecture)
        {
            if (guard.AgainstNull(courseId, nameof(courseId))) return BadRequest();

            if (!courseService.GetCourseById(courseId)) return NotFound();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(lecture);

            return View();
        }
```

But when I submit the form it always returns null.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Comment: Hello, I just upload the code as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used `asp-for`. Apparently, because I generate HTML dynamically and `asp` can't bind this. I replaced it with `name` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

While the code for the backend REST API method that will consume the values from the form indicated in your question is not present, I must assume that the method has an `[HttpPost]` annotation and the number of parameters in the method are more than one.

If that's the case, I suggest to replace the parameters with the `AddDescriptionViewModel` type.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post (AddDescriptionViewModel model)
{
     //your implementation here
}
```

Update: courseID is already part of your AddLectureFormModel properties. If you are having problems with getting through with the POST method, that is because you have 2 parameters in your Post method. If you need to assign value to a courseID in a particular view model (which can be from a form submission), you can set it explicitly.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody]AddLectureFormModel lecture)
{
     lecture.CourseId = \\either hardcode or you have a method here wherein you get the max from database and increment it by 1.
}
```

Comment: I have both. One get and one post action in my lecture controller. I just edit 
the article.

Comment: courseID is already part of your AddLectureFormModel properties. If you are having problems with saving the entity, that is because you have 2 parameters in your Post method. If you need to assign value to a courseID in a particular view model, you can set it explicitly.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see that I made this mistake. Thank you I will fix it.